# .htaccess 301 redirect page specific + wildcard the rest

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The site I'm working has moved to a new domain, with a completely different site structure and file naming.

I've set up a .htaccess file to re-direct important pages to the equivalent pages on the new domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /oldpage1/ http://www.newdomain.org/newpage1
Redirect 301 /folder/oldpage2/ http://www.newdomain.org/newpage2
Redirect 301 /oldpage3/ http://www.newdomain.org/folder/another-newpage
...
```

...and so on.

Now, I want to catch all other URLs under the old domain and direct them to the homepage of the new site. So something like:

```
Redirect 301 /*/ http://www.newdomain.org
```

But how is this really done?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Upfront, `RewriteEngine On` is not necessary with [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directives, because [`RewriteEngine`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) is part of `mod_rewrite`, and `Redirect` belongs to `mod_alias`. These are two different ways of achieving a similar goal.

---

Now, just to answer the question, you may use [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for this

```
RedirectMatch / http://www.newdomain.org
```

This will redirect any path from the old domain to the home page of the new domain.

---

Please note, that the [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive uses the "old" URL as a prefix

> Then any request **beginning with URL-path** will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

This means

```
Redirect /oldpage1/ http://www.newdomain.org/newpage1
```

will redirect all URLs, that *start* with `/oldpage1/`, not just `oldpage1` alone.

---

And finally, *never* test with [`301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!

Comment: They don’t want to keep the path, but redirect all those “other” URLs to the root of the new domain, so this needs a RewriteRule.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, I missed that.